# Scraping an ASP.NET website with NodeJS

Tags: asp.net, node.js, request

i am trying to login to my supplier website programatically and get the resseller price by code. i have my username and password provided by the supplier to use in the website which is powred by ASP.NET. i tried to use the request module but got no luck with it.
this the code i used so far :

```
var request = require('request');
var j = request.jar();
var request = request.defaults({ jar : j }) //it will make the session default for every request
//...
request({
    url:"https://www.XXXXX.com/login.aspx",
    method:"POST",
    form:{
    ctl00$cpholder$txtUserName:"YYYYYYYY",
    ctl00$cpholder$txtPassword:"ZZZZZZZZ"
}
},
function(err,response,body){
    console.log(err);
    // here i try to access the product page like a reseller

    request({
        url:"https://www.XXXXXX.com/productdetails.aspx?id=20000028&itemno=90NB0CL1-M08420", 
        method:"GET",
    }, function(err, response, body){
        console.log(err);

        //Some logic
    });
});
}
```

this is the login form code ( in pastebin because it is very long )
https://pastebin.com/kwuRdLX4

please help

Comment: Ask your supplier if they provide an API to access their site in ways _other_ than logging in on their web site. You're mocking a login only. That's not the only thing protected resources do.

Comment: Thank you. But they dont. I want just to make my job easier by comparing my prices and changing them according to their prices. They dont and will not accept that

Comment: Putting the risk of your activity being a policy violation of your business relationship aside, then you'll have to do more than the above. Inspect the _full_ http request and response handshakes across the board and see if you can mock _all_ of them reliably. Best ~